# Какие проблемы создает переключение контекста CPU?

Tags: многопоточность, cpu, процессор, процесс

Как я понимаю все движется в сторону "много мелких но слабых ядер". Правильно ли я понимаю, что у каждого ядра может быть свой контекст выполнения?

Сколько времени занимает переключения контекста? В том плане, что если у процессора (давайте ради интереса ARM возьмем) 8 ядер, то можно ли говорить о том, что он сможет выполнять больше задач одновременно (к примеру обслуживание сетевых подключений) чем более мощный к примеру двухядерный i5 ?

Ведь по идее на двухядерном i5 с ростом количества задач будет расти время на переключение между задачами, а на 8-ми ядерном ARM можно на это же самое будет тратиться в 4 раза меньше времени?

Есть где-то какие-то числовые сравнения по время затратам на переключения контекста? С точки зрения планирования оптимального количества потоков.

В каких случаях модель асинхронной обработки с использованием файберов (легких потоков) будет ни эффективна? Когда ядер будет много или когда задачи будут "тяжелые". Тогда мне не понятен термин "тяжелая задача". Ведь по идее на каждый поток все равно дается лишь определенный квант времени потоку реально было нужно идет перещелкивания. Т.е. грубо говоря потоку планировщик дал 10 миллисекунд, а он отработал за 1. И все остальное время он будет простаивать.

Я правильно рассуждаю?

Comment: Возьмите конкретный процессор и найдите техническое описание на него. Разработчики процессоров в документации указывают сколько тактов выполняется та или иная операция, включая переключение контекста. Обычно речь при переключении идет о сотнях тактов, в то время как большинство обычных операций происходят за 1 такт. И планировщик дает например ДО 10 мс, если поток меньше времени занял - больше достанется другим. И не думайте, что переключение контекста происходит только когда процесс/планировщик захотели. Есть еще аппаратные прерывания, при которых контекст полюбому переключится

Comment: А на что уходят сотни тактов? И там корректно о тактах говорить или о миллисекундах?

Как работают файберы (которые в D и Go есть)? Они не вызывают переключение контекста?

Comment: я не смотрел что такое файберы, вопрос в том кто ими управляет, ели ОС то переключение контекста будет полюбому потому как уровень привилегий при доступе в память другой. Из за этого собственно и много времени. Надо сохранить состояние всех регистров в текущем стеке, загрузить сегментные регистры, с проверкой эффективных прав. В ms вряд ли уместно считать. ms=1/1000с, тактовая частота 1 GHz = 1 миллиард тактов в секунду

Comment: И овременные ядра на ходу меняют реальную тактовую частоту, одни и те же операции могут выполниться за разное время, так что читать надо в тактах

Answer (score 2):

У полноценных ядер полностью свой контекст выполнения - свой IP (instrustion pointer), набор регистров и набор АЛУ. Во многих процессора ещё и неразделяемый кэш свой. У HyperTreading-ядер - только свой IP и набор регистров. А это значит, что если процесс использует много арифметики и/или интенсивно работает с памятью и использует много кэш-памяти, то два таких процесса на соседних HT-ядрах будут активно мешать друг другу и могут в худшем случае работать вместе медленнее одного.

Но как будет дело обстоять в конкретном случае - сильно зависит от процесса, конечно.